# How do I iterate through httpServiceCall?

Tags: android, api, httphandler

I am requesting data from an API. TheMovieDB API.

They have their results on pages of 20 results. To get multiple pages I have to call the httpServiceCall on the same FINAL_LINK, however, incrementing the page_number every time.

All the pages have the same objects.

This is my code:
https://gist.github.com/sebi1995/f7fcebc463e9e5a28522db9690156a4a

When I run the application, it iterates through the same URL, never incrementing the page_number int.

```
E/HttpHandler: IOException: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=KEY&language=en-UK
E/HttpHandler: IOException: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=KEY&language=en-UK
E/HttpHandler: IOException: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=KEY&language=en-UK
E/HttpHandler: IOException: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=KEY&language=en-UK
E/HttpHandler: IOException: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=KEY&language=en-UK
E/HttpHandler: IOException: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=KEY&language=en-UK
```

The 1 is the page number.

Why is it not updating the FINAL_LINK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `QUERY_TYPE` String only **ONCE**, it never changes, so it stays at 1. Try changing it in your for loop so you actually modify the String instead of declaring it ONCE.

Also next time post the code directly in your question and not on an off-site.

Comment: for (int i = movie_id; i < 4; i++) {
                FINAL_LINK = QUERY_URL + QUERY_TYPE + API_KEY + "&" + LANGUAGE;
                String jsonString = hH.makeServiceCall(FINAL_LINK);
                if (jsonString != null) {
                    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

                    map.put("id", movie_id);
                    movieList.add(map);
                }
            }

Comment: I still don't see you updating the `QUERY_TYPE` value